# PointSeries point not visible

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am using LightningChartJs vs 2.0.1 and I am trying to create a chartXY with pointSeries.

Here is the part of the react component I have

```
const MyFontSettings = new FontSettings({ size: 12 });
const MytickStyle = new VisibleTicks({
  labelFillStyle: new SolidFill({
    color: ColorHEX("#000"),
    tickLength: 8,
  }),
  gridStrokeStyle: new SolidFill({
    color: ColorHEX("#FFF"),
  }),
  gridStrokeLength: 0,
});
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({ container: "Mycontainer" });
chart
  .setTitle("My plot")
  .setTitleFillStyle((solidFill) => solidFill.setColor(ColorHEX("#000")))
  .setTitleMarginTop(0)
  .setTitleMarginBottom(0)
  .setChartBackgroundFillStyle((solidFill) =>
    solidFill.setColor(ColorHEX("#FFF"))
  )
  .setBackgroundFillStyle((solidFill) =>
    solidFill.setColor(ColorHEX("#FFF"))
  )
  .setZoomingRectangleStrokeStyle(
    new SolidLine({
      fillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX("#000") }),
    })
  )
  .setTitleFont(MyFontSettings)
  .setMouseInteractions(false);
// .setAutoCursorMode(AutoCursorModes.disabled);
// Configure X-axis of chart to be progressive and have nice interval.
chart
  .getDefaultAxisX()
  .setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Numeric, (styler) =>
    styler.setMajorTickStyle(MytickStyle).setMinorTickStyle(MytickStyle)
  )
  .setNibStyle(emptyLine)
  .setTitle("RR(n) ms")
  .setTitleFont(MyFontSettings);
chart
  .getDefaultAxisY()
  .setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Numeric, (styler) =>
    styler.setMajorTickStyle(MytickStyle).setMinorTickStyle(MytickStyle)
  )
  .setNibStyle(emptyLine)
  .setTitle("RR(n-1) ms")
  .setTitleFont(MyFontSettings);
let pointSeries = chart
  .addPointSeries()
  .setPointSize(50)
  .setPointFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX("#14ADF4") }));
let arr = [];
axios
  .get(`${base_url}/api/myplot/${props.selected.entity}`)
  .then((res) => {
    arr = res.data;
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
setTimeout(() => {
  for (let point of arr) {
    pointSeries.add(point);
  }
}, 3000);
```

I can confirm that the points are added as when I hover over the chart The points are highlighted by the autocursor but I cannot see them

Comment: Check that your browser supports ANGLE_instanced_arrays WebGL extension. You can check it by visiting https://webglreport.com/ and looking if the extension is listed under "Supported Extensions" list. LightningChart JS 2.0.0 and above require that extension to work properly.

Comment: @Snekw I'm using the latest version of chrome .

Comment: I have been able to reproduce this issue using latest chrome on mac. I'm currently debugging the issue.

Comment: We have pushed LCJS v2.0.2 to npm today. It should solve your issue.